# Comparing two bitmaps against each other for match as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, bitmap

I'm trying to position an image on top of another image based upon the make-up of the smaller image. The smaller image is a cut-out of a larger image and I need it to be positioned exactly on the larger image to make it look like a single image, but allow for separate filters and alphas to be applied. As the images are not simple rectangles or circles, but complex satellite images, I cannot simply redraw them in code. I have quite a few images and therefore do not feel like manually finding the position of each image every and hard setting them manually in actionscript. Is there any way for me to sample a small 5-10 sq. pixel area against the larger image and set the x and y values of the smaller image if a perfect match is found? All the images are in an array and iterating through them has already been set, I just need a way to sample and match pixels. My first guess was to loop the images pixel by pixel right and down, covering the whole bitmap and moving to the next child in the array once a match was found, leaving the matched child where it was when the perfect match was found.

Comment: why don't you post at least pseudocode for what you're doing and tell us what's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

There may be an option that uses copypixels to achieve what you want. You can use the bitmapdata.rect value to determine the size of the sample you want, and loop through the bigger bitmap using thet rectangle and a moving point. Let's see if I can code this out...

```
function findBitmapInBitmap(tinyimg:BitmapData, largeimg:BitmapData):Point {
    var rect:Rectangle = tinyimg.rect;
    var xbound:uint = largeimg.rect.width;
    var ybound:uint = largeimg.rect.height;
    var imgtest:BitmapData = new BitmapData(tinyimg.rect.width, tinyimg.rect.height);

    for (var ypos:uint = 0, y <= ybound, y++) {
        for (var xpos:uint = 0, x <= xbound, x++) {
            imgtest.copyPixels(largeimg, rect, new Point(xpos, ypos);
            if (imgtest.compare(tinyimg) == 0) return new Point(xpos, ypos);
        }
    }

    return new Point(-1,-1); // Dummy value, indicating no match.

}
```

Something along those lines should work - I'm sure there's room for code elegance and possible optimization. However, it seems like something like this method would be very slow, since you'd have to check each pixel for a match.

There is a better way. Split your big image into layers, and use the blitting technique to composite them at runtime. In your case, you could create a ground texture without satellites, and then create the satellites separately, and use the copyPixels method to place them whereever you want. Google "blitting in as3" to find some good tutorials. I'm currently working on a game project that uses this technique and it's a very good method.

Good luck!

Edit: Forgot to code in a default return statement. Using this method, you'd have to return an invalid point (like (-1,-1)) and check for it outside the function. Alternatively, you could just copy your small bitmap to the big one within the function, which would be much more logical, but I don't know your requirements.

Comment: I had just worked something out very similar to this before you answered. I went a step further and tried to ensure the point it samples isn't an empty pixel in the smaller bitmap since they are very often irregular shapes without corners. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Shammr0ck Hmm, you're using the per-pixel method. If you must go that route, you could feasibly only check the first byte of the pixel if your images support transparency - if the first byte is 0x00, skip the check. That way, you would only be checking colors against colors. I still, however, think that for what you seem to be doing, true blitting would be the better answer, as you could do color changes behind the scenes and place your images without worrying about offsets and overlaps. Maybe you could elaborate on your project? It sounds interesting.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to look at blitting yet so I've left it where it lies right now. I'm creating interactive maps for different companies and didn't feel like manually setting image locations when loading external images on top of the main main image. I haven't quite worked out a perfect solution for my needs as the images are cut from the main map and the image editor attempts to anti-alias them and the edges are then not able to match anything in the original image. I plan to use a blacklist array to prevent the checker from matching that location if no match is found.

Comment: @Shammr0ck Ah, I see - your source image already contains the smaller bitmaps, and you don't have a copy of the map without the interactive images on it. Yeah, that's pretty rough - if that is the case, your method would likely be the best way to deal with it (as your options are limited in that regard). Best of luck with it, hope it works out for you. You may try using a pixel editor like MSPaint for your cuts, which won't antialias anything.

Answer (score 1):

For the actual comparison, there's [BitmapData.compare](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare%28%29) which returns the number 0 if the BitmapData objects are equivalent.

Comment: You still have to cycle trough the pixel data to check if there is pixel color different than 0.

Comment: I'm not comparing two bitmaps so much as trying to find a smaller one inside another larger bitmap. Compare doesn't accomplish that for me.

Comment: I was answering the only question I saw, "Is there any way for me to sample a small 5-10 sq. pixel area against the larger image and set the x and y values of the smaller image if a perfect match is found?"

Answer (score 1):

You need to find pixel sequence in the big image. `BitmapData.getPixel` gives you pixel value. So get first pixel from small image, find it in big image, then continue comparing until you find full match. If you have trouble to code that, feel free to ask.

Comment: That's what I had in mind, but I'm not sure how to make it work just right. I posted what I have below.