# compare two images and check equality

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, image-processing

do you know any source or info about comparing images within as3/flash?

I want to compare two images and check if the images are the same or not.

Check this example:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/825/imagecompare.jpg/

Any clues? Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427691/comparing-two-bitmaps-against-each-other-for-match-as3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the duplicate answers,

I believe you can also use [BitmapData.compare()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare%28%29)

An example taken from the link, consider the following two BitmapData objects:

```
 var bmd1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(50, 50, true, 0xFFFF8800);
 var bmd2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(50, 50, true, 0xCCCC6600);
 var diffBmpData:BitmapData = bmd1.compare(bmd2) as BitmapData;
 trace ("0x" + diffBmpData.getPixel(0,0).toString(16); // 0x332200
```

---

**Code Sample (for Percentage Difference) :**

Don't how correct the results are, this is what I brewed up for a percentage :

```
var bmd1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(225, 225);
bmd1.draw(mc1);
var bmd2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(225, 225);
bmd2.draw(mc2);

var diffBmpData:BitmapData = bmd1.compare(bmd2) as BitmapData;

var diff:int = 0;
var total:int = 225 * 225;

for(var i=0; i<225; i++)
    for(var j=0; j<225; j++)
        diff += (diffBmpData.getPixel(i,j) != 0)? 1 : 0; 

info.text = Math.round((diff / total * 100)).toString();
```

where : **info** is a TextBox, **mc1** & **mc2** are two movieclips on stage.

I think you can make it better by comparing individual values (i.e how much different a pixel is) rather than a boolean *is-pixel-similar* match.

---

**Result:** (White space around the round image would be included)

[image]

Comment: thank you loxxy, do you have an idea, how it can result a percentage of difference?

Comment: Iterate over each pixel of diffBmpData using getPixel32(i,j)...  Count the ones which give 0 difference & use it for percentage. For a large image this should give a fair percentage...

Answer (score 3):

Using [`BitmapData.compare()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare%28%29) will return `0` if the pixel values are identical.

```
trace(bmd1.compare(bmd2)); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to loxxy & xLite's answers, if you need to know how to get the BitmapData from an image file:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

loader.load( new URLRequest ( "http://www.fake.url.path/image.jpg" ) );

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var bmp:Bitmap = loader.content as Bitmap;
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = bmp.data; 
    //bitmapData.Compare(...)
}
```

Also see [loading image by Loader.loadBytes(byteArray)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110803/loading-image-by-loader-loadbytesbytearray?rq=1)