# Actionscript 3 number drawing recognition

Tags: actionscript-3, gesture-recognition

I am working on a game to compare a kid drawing (with mouse or gesture) to numbers from 1 to 9, is converting the drawing to bitmap and compare it with number converted to bitmap a good idea?
and how to handle the difference in size (width-height) between the 2 images? 
Thanks

Comment: Really!? Sorry but no...

Comment: what's wrong with my question?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to ask people to write code for you.  Try doing it yourself first, then ask about any problems you encountered.

Comment: i did not ask for code, i said help me with the idea like where to start

Comment: i got the question edited, maybe this looks better, and sorry if it was not in a proper shape first time

Comment: why everyone is so aggressive? i am asking if it is a good idea or not

Comment: this could help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401773/compare-two-images-and-check-equality) and concerning your second question, you'd scale one of the images to be the same size as the other image, then compare.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the mistaken question , it is my first question here so i still have alot to learn here

Comment: And I apologize for my aggresive comments earlier. But you should look into the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what type of questions get better responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with image comparison, but it's pretty tricky to get it right.
What I would suggest is:

- Pre-generate small (10x10 pixels or even smaller) grayscale images of the numbers and blur them a little
- Convert drawing to grayscale
- Blur drawing a bit
- Crop borders from drawing
- Resize drawing down to the size of your number images;
- Compare the small drawing image with the generated number images, pixel by pixel and be lenient to what you accept as a match.

Comment: this sounds a very good way to do it, i will give it a try, thanks alot

Comment: Hi @HamadaSamir if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: As I said, there is no obligation to do this. Computer vision problems are challenging, but satisfying when you get right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Mouse Gesture Recognition](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=91)

```
var gesture:MouseGesture  = new MouseGesture(stage);
gesture.addGesture('B','260123401234');
gesture.addEventListener(GestureEvent.MATCH,matchHandler);

function matchHandler(event:GestureEvent):void
{
     trace (event.datas + ' matched !')
}
```

Comment: i gave it a try earlier and it is good but needs more work on the recognition

Comment: Of course, it's necessary to improve the recognition, but this class gives you everything necessary to be able to achieve your goal.